# Something wrong with getTag()

Tags: android

I'm using() setTag and getTag() in a ScrollView with dynamic ImageViews to know which is clicked. This is my code:
`import android.os.Bundle;`
`import android.app.Activity;`
`import android.view.Menu;`
`import android.view.View;`
`import android.widget.ImageView;`
`import android.widget.LinearLayout;`
`import android.widget.TextView;`
`import android.widget.Toast;`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private View cell;
private LinearLayout layoutScroll;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    layoutScroll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_scroll_main_activity);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3 ; i ++){
        cell = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.category_cells, null);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) cell.findViewById(R.id.image_category_cells);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) cell.findViewById(R.id.text_category_cells);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getTag().toString() == "0"){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Text1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if (imageView.getTag().toString() == "1"){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Text2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,v.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
        imageView.setTag(i);
        int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/category1", null, getPackageName());
        imageView.setImageResource(imageResource);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        textView.setText("Texto " + Integer.toString(i + 1));
        layoutScroll.addView(cell);
    }
}
```

Ok, the problem is that I'm getting always a Toast that says 0, 1 , 2 or 3 depending on the ImageView I click. My question is, if I get a Toast that says 0 or 1 shouldn't it give me a Toast that says Text1 or Text2?? 
I would appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: Use .equals for String comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings should be compared with .equals()

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29